# Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache returning FALSE although assembly is loaded from GAC

Tags: .net, reflection

I have created a test project to understand reflection. I'm loading an assembly from .NET 4.0 GAC. (As I understand, .NET 4.0 maintains it's GAC in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly)

I wrote the code like this:

```
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\TestReflection\v4.0_1.0.0.0__7ff2353191526e8c\TestReflection.dll");

        if(testAssembly.GlobalAssemblyCache)
            Console.WriteLine(testAssembly.FullName);
```

When I run this code, `GlobalAssemblyCache` property always return FALSE although I'm loading assembly from GAC.

Can someone tell me the reason? Or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You may first want to make sure your assembly is in fact loaded onto the GAC. For doing that you can try the following:

```
gacutil /l System.Data
```

Which would provide with the details of the assembly in the GAC as:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=x86
  System.Data, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
  System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=x86

Number of items = 3
```

Then for loading the assembly from GAC for ReflectionOnly usage you can try the `ReflectionOnlyLoad` instead of `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`

example:

```
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(@"System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=x86");

if (testAssembly.GlobalAssemblyCache) {
    Console.WriteLine(testAssembly.FullName);
    Console.WriteLine(testAssembly.Location);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Not found in GAC");
}
```

The above gives the following output:

```
System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It really seems helpful. But when I run gacutil /l TestReflection.dll , it says 0 assemblies found. But when I actually go to the GAC folder of .NET 4.0, I can see assemblies there. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: @Amey: Are you installing your assembly to the GAC using `gacutil /i <assembly_path>` option?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same option to install assembly in GAC using gacutil.

Comment: @Amey: If the `gacutil /l <assembly_name>` returns 0 assemblies, then the assembly is not in the GAC. Which would be different issue apart from what we are troubleshooting here. Please make sure that the `gacutil \i <assembly_path>` says that it has installed the assembly successfully in the GAC.

Comment: Yes, 'gacutil /i <assembly_path>' says it's installed successfully. Also, when i open the GAC folders of .NET 4.0, I can see assembly there. However, 'gacutil /l <assembly_name>' returns 0 assemblies and in code 'GlobalAssemblyCache' flag too returns 'FALSE' as mentioned in my question.